# Jsf2 view parameters and viewscoped beans

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

How can I access the view parameters from a viewscoped bean? 
I have a page almost with the same content as this:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="name" value="#{goToUserpageRequest.name}" />
</f:metadata>

<ui:define name="content">
    <h:outputText value="#{user.name}" styleClass="text"></h:outputText>
    <h:outputText value="#{user.description}" styleClass="text"></h:outputText>
</ui:define>
```

GoToUserpageRequest is a bean which I use to redirect to this page, so I can send the value for name.
User is my viewscoped bean. I want to pass the value of viewParam name to user.name. How can I do that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this information using the [external context](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getExternalContext%28%29) from your [context](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getCurrentInstance%28%29). See the [request parameters](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestParameterMap%28%29).

However, I would try to use a [request](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/RequestScoped.html) scope bean and [inject](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedProperty.html) the view and parameter scope values into that. You can then manipulate your view scoped object from there. This approach is easier to unit test.

---

EDIT:

Here is a sample implementation:

```
@ManagedBean @RequestScoped
public class NameUpdater {
    @ManagedProperty("#{param.name}") private String name;
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    @ManagedProperty("#{user}") private User user;
    public User getUser() { return user; }
    public void setUser(User user) { this.user = user; }

    @PostConstruct public void init() {
        if(name != null) user.setName(name);
    }
}
```

In order to create the request scoped bean, the binding expression would change to something like:

```
<h:outputText value="#{nameUpdater.user.name}" />
```

Comment: From where should I manipulate the view scoped object? Because I am redirecting in the request.

Comment: @bliof - perform your logic in the request scope object

Comment: and not to use the view scoped one? And how to pass the value for exmple of the description? It could be a bit too long..

Comment: @bliof - I've added an example - the view and parameter values are injected into a request scope artefact; the expression is changed to reference the view scoped artefact via the request scope one; when `@PostConstruct` is called, the parameter value is set into the view scope object. It is a limitation of JSF's managed beans that you can't inject into a wider scope.

Answer (score 2):

There is an easier way for your case which I have just figured out while looking for a solution for the same situation.
 just use this in your xhtml together :

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="name" value="#{goToUserpageRequest.name}" />
</f:metadata>

 <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{MY_BEAN.setName(goToUserpageRequest.name)}"/>
```

so you can send the goToUserpageRequest.name value back to your redirected view's bean (I called MY_BEAN)